# wordpress htaccess to block a query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

If this was already answered for a similar question, I apologize in advance. I am trying to block requests with a query string that looks like this:

`?alt_id=nnnn&alt_ts=&alt_ts=&alt_ts...`

where `nnnn` is some number and `...`indicates that `&alt_ts=` repeats numerous times.

rather than testing for this specific query string, I thought testing for just `&alt_ts=&alt_ts` would be good enough to start with, so I added this rule to .htaccess, but it doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&alt_ts=&alt_ts).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, it does not work. I hope there's a htaccess expert who can fix this. Thanks.

this is my current .htaccess file, modified as suggested by anubhava:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^alt_id=[^&]+&alt_ts= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+[^?]*\?alt_id=[^&]+&alt_ts= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Make sure this is **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine` line in your main WP .htaccess file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it's not working. I type in `domainname.com/page-name/?alt_id=1&alt_ts=` in browser address bar and it displays `domainname.com/page-name`

Comment: that worked! thanks a million :) any idea why our previous attempts failed?

Comment: Also, the new rule produces a 500 error instead of the 403 I was expecting, but as long as the request is denied, I don't mind

Comment: looking at apache error log, it shows, `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Actually you can include `ErrorDocument 403 default` at top of .htaccess to fix since there is some faulty `ErrorDocument` somewhere. Reason why earlier version didn't work because WP forwards everything to `index.php` and that changes `REQUEST_URI` and possibly `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: you are right again! that did it. I'm most grateful for the assistance.

Comment: Super useful, really saved my bacon!